# How to pass a parameter in an onclick function?

Tags: javascript

I would like to use an onclick function which takes a parameter in JavaScript.

Calling `button.onclick = someAction` works. Is there a way to use a function that takes parameter(s) instead? For example:

```
function loadAPP() {
    button = someButton(param);
    button.onclick = someAction(param);
    document.body.appendChild(button);
}
```

Comment: Yes its absolutely possible. Give it a try i will definitely work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Standard practice is to [use an anonymous function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onclick#Example):

```
button.onclick = () => someAction(param);
```

or

```
button.onclick = function() { someAction(param) };
```

if your environment doesn't support arrow syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) and bind the parameter to your function.

```js
const someAction = param => console.log(param);
const button = document.createElement('button');
button.onclick = someAction.bind(button,'this is my params');
document.body.appendChild(button);
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I know is include the value in `data-*` attributes and call it inside the click event function

```js
var btn = document.getElementById("test");
btn.onclick = function(){
  console.log(btn.getAttribute("data-param1"));
  console.log(btn.getAttribute("data-param2"));
}
```

```html
<button id="test" data-param1="value1" data-param2="value2">
  Test
</button>
```